# Reboot can not start up my host machine

Tags: centos

I have a host machine (CentOS7.2), and it works perfect, but when I restart it, it can not start anymore.

Getting the below information:

> DHCP...\

[image]

---

**EDIT**

I want to set it boot from the disk, but there is only one choice:

[image]

Comment: Server tries to boot from "Intel® Boot Agent XE" - if you dont need it deactivate it to boot from Harddisk

Comment: @Vafa See my EDIT, my friend. it only has one choice here.

Comment: Have you tried to press "Ctrl-S" during the boot time  to configure the Boot Agent XE ?

Comment: What are the possible options for "Network Boot Protocol" ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set this in the BIOS to set the boot order.

When system starting, you should click the shortcut key(it changes by the mainboard model, it maybe `<del，Esc，F1，F2，F8，F9，F10，F11，F12>`).

If you in, you can change the boot order in the corresponding place:

[image]